# Show a sub item on the recycler view after click on an item in the recycler view

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview

I'm working in a android application i want to show a sub item's in the recycler view witch it included in the navigation drawer after a click in one of the item's

here's a part of my code who handle the click event`    class AdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        ImageView row_icon;
        TextView row_text;

```
    public AdapterViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        row_icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_icon);
        row_text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_text);

        row_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

by clicking on item just add new item below that item and notify your adapter and you will get new item (you can customize that item to look like sub item)